# It is possible to use "to get" instead of "to be" in passive voice?

Tags: difference, passive-voice

Are the below sentences passive?

1. my car got stolen?
2. to get dressed.

It is possible to use "to get" instead of "to be" in passive voice, for any tense and verb?

Comment: Yes; _get_-passives are an informal alternant to _be_-passives. "My car got stolen" is okay. But "We quickly got dressed" is an adjectival passive, not a verbal one,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the "to be" verb can be used in active and state verbs, while the "to get" can be used with action, not state verbs.

> the glass was broken. (action verb)
>   the glass got broken. (action verb)
>   my car got stolen.

But, "to get (un)dressed, get married, get lost" are expression, and not in passive voice.

Comment: "The glass was broken" is ambiguous between a verbal passive and an adjectival one. If it denotes an action (someone or something  broke the glass) it's verbal, but if it denotes a state (the window was in the state resulting from prior breaking) then it's an adjectival passive.

Answer (score 0):

More correct to say, "My car was stolen from the parking lot." "Got stolen" would be considered slang.